# What is meant by "empirical survival" in Taleb's Tail Risk of Contagious Diseases paper?

Tags: statistics

Nassim Taleb e.a. published a paper [Tail Risk of Contagious Diseases](https://www.academia.edu/42307438/Tail_Risk_of_Contagious_Diseases]) which contains the following plot, based on 62 historical disease outbreaks:

[image: Causualties vs. Empirical Survival]

I think I understand Zipf's law from the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zipf%27s_law) example, which plots word rank vs. word frequency:

[image: rank vs. frequency]

But I'm confused about the units used in Taleb's chart. What is "empirical survival" here?

Comment: Someone on Twitter pointed me here, so I'll read that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_distribution_function

Comment: Survival function is 1-CDF, empirical survival indicates 1 - empirical CDF.

Comment: My guess would be the Kaplan-Meier empirical survival function described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaplan%E2%80%93Meier_estimator. In any case, you can check against the numbers in Appendix 1.

Answer (score 1):

[cwindolf](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/383062/cwindolf) answered the question:

> Survival function is `1-CDF`, empirical survival indicates `1 - empirical CDF`

I zoomed in and annotated the image to make it a bit more intuitive.

[image: zoom]

The first three dots are outbreaks that, after adjusting for world population, had 2,000 rescaled casualties. The next dot is the Yemen Cholera outbreak with 4,000 rescaled casualties (see table on page 6, 6th column), etc.

The y coordinate of each dot is given by 1 minus:
[image]

So for the first dot we have 1 element in the sample, so we get `1 - 1/62 = 0.98`. For the second dot we have two elements in the sample, so `1 - 2/62 = 0.97`, ..., the fourth is `1 - 4/62 = 0.93`.